# How to change a textbox text with prevAll()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used this code to change the text of the previous textbox but its not working, what should i do ?
I tried to add a CSS class to be sure that it finds the textbox and of course it finds that textbox but can't change the value.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("li.start").prevUntil("div.stop","input").text("!");
                // $("li.start").prevUntil("div.stop","input").value("!"); not working too
            });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width:500px;" class="siblings">
        <div class="stop" > </div>
     <input id="Text1" type="text" />  
     <ul> 
    <li>li (the previous sibling)</li>
    <li>li (the previous )</li>                            
     <li>li (the previous)</li>
     <li class="start">li (sibling with class name "start")</li>
    <li>li (sibling)</li>
    <li>li (sibling)</li>
  </ul>   
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code is invalid, `<ul>` can't contain `<div>` or `<input>`. Also, `prevUntil` exclude the selector.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon i updated my code , what about now ? not working ...

Comment: @MohammadOlfatMiri what are you trying to change? the `input` id Text1?

Comment: @Huangism yes i want to change Text1 entered Text

Comment: `$("li.start").parent().prev("input").val("!");` : http://jsfiddle.net/FZk66/

Comment: @MohammadOlfatMiri I assume you have a NEED to go from `.start` or you can just target the id directly. With the given code you can just do `$("li.start").parent().prev().val("!");`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon ty it Works , the same as Siamak.A.M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `val()` for input like this: [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/L3z3H/)

```
$("li.start").prevUntil("div.stop").val('!');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made some JS syntax errors.

So you want to find the "input" [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/prevuntil/) (that is the second parameter) that precede "li.start" up to the preceding "div.stop" and give them a new HTML value text?

Here is the **UPDATED** (as for your updated question) fiddle with my suggestions: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8JQ4A/3/)

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("li.start").prevUntil("div.stop, input").html('!');
  });
```

As jQuery reference for prevAll() method, it affected only for the siblings, that is not your HTML. Combine parent method and prev method, instead.

```
   $("li.start").parent("ul").prev('input').val('!'); //UPDATED
```

Comment: Why not just do `.text()` the proper way? `$("li.start").prevUntil("div.stop,input").text('!');` but OP's html is invalid anyway so a lot of things needs to change

Comment: no its not working , i updated my question ! @Huangism